# i have installed koala & compile scss file but still sass css is not working

Tags: css, sass

I am using sass css i have an issue in compile nested css. I am using Koala for compiling. I have tried a lot of things but its still giving me such kind of error.

I am using this css for test please let me know if have issue in that code

```
.first{
    background: blue;

    p{color:red;}

}
```

can anyone please help me out from this how can is do that?

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: sass css is not working.it is working like normal css. not taking variables or any other functionality of sass.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SASS the code should be without `{}` and `,`

SASS code:

```
.first
   background: blue

   p
     color:red
```

or just change you file format from `.sass` to `.scss` and everithing should works fine

Comment: it gives below error : i have saved a file with extension sass 
inconsistent indication: 5 space were used for indentation but the on line 4 of --path-- use:trace for backtrace .

Comment: it happen because in my code spaces aren't 100% correct it's just example,
check this link if u want to get correct one- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOzxPj